# Why does my unit test fail my apex class when i try to use https instead of http

Tags: https, salesforce, apex

The problem i'm encountering is the moment i try switching from http to https, my unit tests fail and i can't push my code to production.

I'm trying to push some data from an apex class to another framework. Since this data might be a bit sensitive i'd like to encrypt it with the client certificate options offered by salesforce.

```js
public class someclaass { 
    @future(callout=true) 
    public static void SendData(String id, String name, String token) { 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        req.setEndpoint('https://someurl.com/');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setClientCertificateName('certificatename');
        req.setBody('{"id" : "' + id + '", "name" : "' + name + '", "token" : "' + token + '"}');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    }
    
}
```

```js
@istest
global class Some_mock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    
    /* This method fakes a reponse to our HTTP request to Blue10 */
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        
        String endpoint = req.getEndpoint();
        system.debug(endpoint);
        System.assert(endpoint.startsWith('https://someurl.com'));
        String responseBody = '';
        String destination = '';
        
        // get the actual API function we're calling
        String[] parts = endpoint.split('/');
        destination = parts[parts.size()-1];
        
        system.debug(destination);
        
        if(destination == 'sendData') {
            System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());
            responseBody = Some_mock.SomeMock();
        } else {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'We don\'t have a test case for this API function yet: '+destination);
            //System.assert(true == false);
        }
        
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody(responseBody);
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }  
    
    public static String SomeMock() {
        String body = 
            ' {'+
            '   "status": "success",'+
            '   "message": null,'+
            '   "code": 200'+
            ' }';
        return body;
    }
}
```

```js
@isTest
private class SomeTest { 
    static testMethod void validateSomeClass() { 
    
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Some_mock());
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        Some.Senddata('id', 'name', 'token');
        List<SomeInvocable.SomeVariable> SomeList = new List<SomeInvocable.SomeVariable>();
        SomeInvocable.SomeVariable orobj = new SomeInvocable.SomeVariable();
        orobj.id = 'id';
        orobj.name = 'name';
        orobj.token = 'token';
        SomeList.add(orobj);
        SomeInvocable.sendMessage(SomeList);
        
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
    
}
```

The above works the moment i set http:// in both urls instead of https://, but i have no clue what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The errormessage i got was:
Could not run tests on class xxx because: connection was cancelled here

Comment: Have u already define a remote site?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm

Comment: I did, same results >.<. I thought the mock class would take care of the call like that.

Comment: It got trough the test right now. The only thing i did was supplying a custom port number. Could that have changed the result?

Comment: Good question. Which port do u set? 443?

Comment: No, a custom one (above 1024). But it should default to 443 if you set nothing right?

Comment: I would think so yes

Comment: I don't like the sound of what's going on here. Are you trying to unit test that the Force.com platform knows what HTTPS is and how to handle it? That's really not your concern. What if it didn't? You can't fix it anyway! Make sure that your methods that provide the data that's going to be transferred do what they should and trust the platform. Were you using Java or .NET, would you write a unit test to make sure the OS saved a file correctly?